# Change size Frame Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

```
textFrame1 = Frame(mainFrame,bd=5,width=100)
    textFrame1.pack(fill=BOTH,side=LEFT,expand=YES)

    self.textFile1 = Text(textFrame1,wrap=None)
    sbVer1 = Scrollbar(textFrame1,orient=VERTICAL,command=self.textFile1.yview)
    sbHor1 = Scrollbar(textFrame1,orient=HORIZONTAL,command=self.textFile1.xview)

    sbVer1.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    sbHor1.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)

    self.textFile1.config(yscrollcommand=sbVer1.set,xscrollcommand=sbHor1.set)
    self.textFile1.pack()

    # --------------------------------------------

    textFrame2 = Frame(mainFrame,bd=5,width=1)
    textFrame2.pack(fill=BOTH,side=RIGHT,expand=YES)

    self.textFile2 = Text(textFrame2,wrap=None)
    sbVer2 = Scrollbar(textFrame2,orient=VERTICAL,command=self.textFile2.yview)
    sbHor2 = Scrollbar(textFrame2,orient=HORIZONTAL,command=self.textFile2.xview)

    sbVer2.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    sbHor2.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)

    self.textFile2.config(yscrollcommand=sbVer2.set,xscrollcommand=sbHor2.set)
    self.textFile2.pack()
```

I want to resize a frame (tkinter python) because it's too large and I want to make it smaller. If you read carefully, I put two frames in this code. The first frame has `width=100` and the second `width=1`. But, when I compile, the result still same. It looks as if the command `width` doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Your code is not complete (and probably not minimal).

Comment: I recommend you read the book "Python and TKinter programming". Very good book, thorough. You can probably find them on eBay for lower prices. That's assuming you really want to use TKinter. I do recommend Qt instead of Tkinter though

Comment: @frankliuao good points. thanks for the book. i would look for it. but btw, why you choose Qt that Tkinter?

Comment: @mbdrian wider application, easier, more useful.

Comment: @frankliuao Qt, then. thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Your text boxes have the default width of 80 characters, and the frames size to fit them. You should set the width and height of your text widgets if you want one of them larger than the other.

Another option, which I wouldn't recommend, is to use `.pack_propagate(False)` on your root window to stop the frames from resizing to fit the widgets.